# add to select box values from multiple model attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to dynamically set options to my select box from another model in Laravel. So I want to do something similar like this:

```
$handymans = Handyman::lists('firstname', 'handyman_id');
```

but, this add to select box only firstname's of the handymans. How can I add also lastname to option value, which will be shown to user? ( not only firstname ). I try do something like this:

```
$handymans = Handyman::lists('firstname', 'lastname','handyman_id');
```

but this doesnt work :( .

Comment: can you post your blade code?

Comment: <div class='form-group'>
    <div style="text-align: center;">{!! Form::label('Handyman: ') !!}</div>
    {!! Form::select('handymans[]', $handymans, 'default',
    array(
    'multiple'=>'multiple',
    'class'=>'form-control'
    ))!!}
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the values through mutator in your class, appending `full_name` attribute to your model, something like this:

```
protected $appends = ['full_name'];

...

public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->firstname.' '.$this->lastname;
}
```

Then try to list it, calling this way:

```
$handymans = Handyman::all()->lists('full_name', 'handyman_id');
```

Comment: this doesnt work. Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `full_name`, `handyman_id` from `handymen`)